# how to get data from extjs store without sort apply on it

Tags: extjs, extjs4.2

i apply data to grid's store with "loadData()" function. i want get json data without any sort apply to data from store on future. i use this code:

Ext.pluck(grid.store.data.items, 'data');

but this return data with sort apply on it. any idea for solve this issue ?

Comment: Your question doesn't really make sense. If you don't want the data sorted,  it won't be sorted. So don't sort it.

Comment: i have a grid with store assign to it  but no proxy assign to it and i fill store with loadData() function. grid has a local sort property and user can change sort of data. for some reason i need get unsorted data from grid's store on other part of application.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If ou load data via proxy setup you can find initial data in `myStore.initialConfig.data.items`.

If you load data with `loadData()` method I can offer you to save initial data as store instance property, like `myStore.rawData = myData`.

[Simple fiddle](https://fiddle.sencha.com/#fiddle/14v3)

Comment: myStore.initialConfig get undefined

Comment: Ah, my fault, you load data with `loadData()` method. Well, in this case I guess you cannot get unsorted data (and its quite correct because you setup your _sotore_ to keep its data sorted in sceratin way). I offer you to save unsorted data anywhere in your application and use it when needed.

Comment: I offer you to add custom property to your store instance (since its just JS object), like `myStore.rawData = myData` and load data as you do `myStore.loadData(myData)`.

Comment: Updated fiddle to reflect this idea